# How to store weekdays data alongwith start time and end time in database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

I am trying to build something which will save, in database, the opening and closing time of a store/shop for each week day.
How can I achieve that?

I thought of making a new table, having 7 columns for 7 days, but what about the times? it will need an extra 14 columns then.

Comment: You can have something like 3 columns  day , startTime and endTime in the database. That should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky.  It is tempting to have three columns:

```
<date of week>  <open time>  <close time>
```

However, this gets tricky for the following circumstances:

- Stores that are open 24 hours a day.
- Stores that close after midnight.
- Stores that have different hours on holidays.
- Stores that close in the middle of the day (this happens in some countries).

The problem is a bit trickier than it sounds.  In a real application, I would probably suggest a calendar table, where there is one row per store open with a full datetime for the open and close.  That calendar could be created, say, two years ahead say once per year.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that stores can have **multiple opening and closing times per day** (easy to check on Google Maps), it may be necessary to have multiple entries per store. So why not use the following structure:

```
store_id   |   day_of_week    |    start_time    |    end_time
```

where `day_of_week` in [0,6].

One thing that's not optimal with this solution is that if a store is open past midnight you are gonna have both a closing and opening time at midnight for two consecutive days, even though the store didn't close and open in reality.

Please note that `store_id` would not be the primary key here, but all columns together (i.e. composite key).